# null is not an object (evalutating 'u.invocationEventNone') - Instabug + Expo Integration

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo, instabug

I'm trying to integrate InstaBug for the first time but keep running into an error at app start-up.

I'm currently running a detached Expo app. I've followed the [setup instructions](https://dashboard.instabug.com/welcome-to-instabug) for my app, however, when running, I get the following error:

`null is not an object (evaluating 'u.invocationEventNone')`

### steps to reproduce

```
# install instabug
$ npm install instabug-reactnative        

# link with RN-cli
$ react-native link instabug-reactnative
```

Then initialize InstaBug in `App.js`

```
/* ./App.js */
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  if (Platform.OS == "ios") {
    Instabug.startWithToken('secret_key', [Instabug.invocationEvent.shake]);
  }
}
```

Add Android Config:

```
/* android/app/src/main/java/[...]/MainApplication.java */
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
    new MainReactPackage(),
    new RNInstabugReactnativePackage.Builder("secret_key", MainApplication.this)
      .setInvocationEvent("shake")
      .build()
}
```

### What I've tried

I've tried installing it with cocoa pods (and ran `pod install`) and `react-native unlink` + manually linking on xCode.

Any help is appreciated

### Versions

```
Expo CLI 3.1.0 environment info:

Binaries:
Node: 10.16.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: 1.7.0 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm: 6.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/npm/xcodebuild

npmPackages:
instabug-reactnative => ^8.7.0
expo: ^33.0.0 => 33.0.7
react: 16.8.3 => 16.8.3
react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz => 0.59.8

npmGlobalPackages:
expo-cli: 3.1.0
```